# Is it possible to force cordova inAppBrowser to use Crosswalk webView?

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser, crosswalk-runtime

In crosswalk it is [possible](https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/cordova/add_plugins) to use cordova plugins

And cordova [inAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) seems to work fine. But it still uses old android browser instead of [crosswalk chromium](https://crosswalk-project.org/#wiki/Downstream-Chromium) (so doesn't support needed HTML5 features).

I can see this by checking user-agent for example:

1) inside the app:

> Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; PHONENAME) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Mobile Crosswalk/7.36.154.13
>   Mobile Safari/537.36 Response Headers

2) inside the inAppBrowser:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; en-us; PHONENAME)
>   AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile
>   Safari/534.30

Answer (score 1):

The Cordova inAppBrowser plugin is implemented with the system WebView component, there're  several differences between the interfaces of WebKit WebView and Crosswalk WebView, so cordova inAppBrowser could not simply changed to fully compatible with Crosswalk webview.

But if your requirement is simple, such as just show a single html5 page with inAppBrower, it's easy to show a Crosswalk webview with several changes to inAppBrowser plugin.

Can you provide more detail about how you use inAppBrowser plugin?

Comment: Basically I need to open certain webpages (where I cannot control their content/headers/etc). When the page is opened I need to inject custom javascript code to run in the context of opened page and receive back data from the page, then close it. This can be done easily with chrome extensions on desktop, but I need this inside cordova app.

So the api for inAppBrowser with its [executeScript](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#executeScript) is enough, the problem is in its lacking html5 support (blob building for example).

Comment: @Gordon it would be great to see some code for the "several changes to inAppBrowser plugin" if possible if you have some

Comment: once crosswalk is integrated will super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); do the trick or do we have to use some other method to use crosswalk's webview

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

https://github.com/Shoety/cordova-plugin-inappbrowserxwalk

It's an inappbrowser which uses crosswalk instead of system WebView.

Comment: you should probably fix it ;-)

Comment: I was unable to run executeScript with it